Better to terminate guard ring to cable shield or leave shield unconnected at load?
I am working on designing a precision rectifier and charge amplifier for a small-signal piezo transducer. This tiny board will be a sensor "load" sending a mV-to-1V amplified analog signal back to an analog front end for further amplification.
Cable lengths are no longer than 10ft with foil shielded cable. The signal itself is clamped to 2.5V to avoid any negative references for a dynamic range between 0 and 5V.
The initial prototype was very similar to the Analog devices reference design cascaded into a non-inverting amplifier. LINK to serve as a "preamp" back over the cable. It functioned well but suffered interference from the device's nearby 2.4GHz WiFi radio (transmitting at approx. -30dBm with the connected gain antenna).
Prototype shielding the PCB worked so I plan to incorporate a shield-can as well as guard trace on the next revision. Based on the Altium Academy video on guard rings: LINK it would seem that if I tie the cable shield to the shield-can and guard ring I can keep the circuit's 0V/"clean" ground separate. (The main processing device reading the analog signal is assumed to be earth grounded) This, however makes me call into question the common convention of it being best to not tie a cable shield at both the source and load side?
